# "How Do I list the main file in package.json"

Tags: npm, bower, yarnpkg

I used to write "main":"index.html" in my bower.json to say that this is the main file.I am in the process of migrating from bower to yarn ...

How do write this main configuration in the new package.json

Answer (score 0):

You most likely don't need to.

If your build tools require you to define main files, i suggest having a look at their documentation for npm or yarn.